# McQuarrie: the Planck distribution law for blackbody radiation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics

The Planck distribution law for blackbody radiation is stated **in terms of frequency** as:

$$
d\rho (\nu, T) = \rho_{\nu}(T)d\nu = \dfrac{8\pi h}{c^3}\dfrac{\nu ^3}{e^{\left(\dfrac{h\nu}{k_B T}\right)}-1}d\nu 
$$

Using the substitutions $\lambda \nu = c$ and $d\nu = \dfrac{-c}{\lambda^2}d\lambda$, the law has also been stated **in terms of wavelength**:

$$
d\rho (\lambda, T) = \rho_{\lambda}(T)d\lambda = \dfrac{8\pi hc}{\lambda^5}\dfrac{1}{e^{\left(\dfrac{hc}{\lambda k_B T}\right)}-1}d\lambda 
$$

I tried the substitutions, and I don't understand what to do with the extra negative sign? How did it just disappear like that?

$$
\begin{align}
& \dfrac{8\pi h}{c^3}\dfrac{\nu ^3}{e^{\left(\dfrac{h\nu}{k_B T}\right)}-1}d\nu \\
=&\dfrac{8\pi h}{c^3}\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{c}{\lambda}\right) ^3}{e^{\left(\dfrac{h\left(\dfrac{c}{\lambda}\right)}{k_B T}\right)}-1}\left( \dfrac{-c}{\lambda ^2} d\lambda \right) \\
=& -\dfrac{8\pi hc}{\lambda^5}\dfrac{1}{e^{\left(\dfrac{hc}{\lambda k_B T}\right)}-1}d\lambda
\end{align}
$$

### Reference

1. Physical Chemistry: A Molecular Approach
   McQuarrie, D. A., Simon, J. D.
   Viva Books Private Limited (2011 edition, 2015 reprint)

Answer (score 3):

The integral operator$$\int_0^{+\infty} dk \rightarrow -\int_{+\infty}^0 \frac{2 \pi}{\lambda^2} d\lambda=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2 \pi}{\lambda^2} d\lambda$$